# $F=ma$, so if acceleration is zero the force must also be zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I was just pushing a huge rock which I couldn't move at all. Given that the acceleration was zero as a result of my efforts, since $F=ma$, doesn't this mean that the force must also have been zero?

But, in reality, I ***was*** applying a force $F$, there ***is*** a huge rock with mass $m$, but the acceleration $a$ I observed was zero.  So does this mean physics denies the existence of my applied force? How can I reconcile this contradiction?

Comment: If acceleration is zero, the *sum* of all forces will be zero for the object in question. This is to say the object is in equilibrium.

Comment: Correct way to write the formula: $$\sum F=ma$$ Never forget the sum sign.

Answer (score 18):

The confusion comes from how you have written the equation. If you write it like this $$F_{net} = ma$$ it will be easier to see your error. You are exerting a force on the boulder, but net force is zero. This means that other forces such as friction are canceling your force out.

[image]

In this case. Friction equals applied force.

Answer (score 2):

It is the net force, not force.

Answer (score 1):

Force = mass * acceleration is the basic simplified version of the equation.
There are more complected formulas available for this that take into account more complicated scenarios; like taking in the account of different forces coming from different directions like in your scenario.

sum(forces) = mass * acceleration

force = the derivative of its linear momentum

and so on ...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_second_law

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is that the total force you are applying on the body **is** **not enough to move the rock**.This means that the total force on the box is zero because **the force of static friction is grater than that of your applied force,which cancels out the effect your force**.As your forces increases the static friction also increases until a point comes when you are able to overcome that force and the body also moves.Now the friction is kinetic friction which has a magnitude lower than that of static friction.If your draw the graph of force vs static and kinetic friction you will see that the static friction line increases steeply until a certain force after that when it starts to move it decreases a little and continues to remain constant(not fully constant,only to an approximation).

Answer (score 1):

This type of question keeps reccuring. I suppose either teachers don't teach this correctly, or students do not pay attention in class. $F=m a$ is really $$\sum F = m a_{cm}$$ These two distinctions (the sum, and the acceleration of the center of mass) make all the difference in the world (At least read on [Newton's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion) of motion).

You push on the rock and the ground is pusing on the rock with a net result *zero*.

At all starts from the following principles:

1. Momentum is mass times velocity of the center of mass $P=m v_{cm}$
2. The effect of a single force over time is to change the momentum $F \mathrm{\Delta} t = \mathrm{\Delta} P$
3. Multiple forces can be combined algebraicly for a net (effective) force which describes the net change in momentum $\sum F \mathrm{\Delta} t = \mathrm{\Delta} P$
4. For a constant mass the change in momentum becomes a change in speed of the center of mass only $\mathrm{\Delta} P = m \mathrm{\Delta} v_{cm}$
5. The change in speed over time is called acceleration $\sum F = m \frac{\mathrm{\Delta} v_{cm}}{\mathrm{\Delta} t} = m a_{cm} $

Understand all these steps and you will be able to understand any situation involving linear motion.